# Limit list output from a map to X entries per line

Tags: java, output

I have a map of words with the key being a keyword from a provided list and the value being a list of integers with the index of the keyword in my document.

I want to limit the entries of the list per line to a set amount. Something like:

```
and =
   [1,2,3,
    4,5,6]
```

but I keep getting:

```
and = 
   [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

What I have right now:

```
private Map<String, List<Integer>> keywordMap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
...
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(properties.getProperty("output.dir") + properties.getProperty("output.file.keyword")))))
{
    int limit = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : keywordMap.entrySet())
    {
        writer.print(entry.getKey() + " =\n" + entry.getValue());
        limit++;

        if (limit == 3)
        {
            writer.print("\n");
            limit = 0;
        }   
    }
}...
```

Also, as a bonus question, how would I go about outputting a situation that the keyword isn't in the document? Or just

```
portmanteau =
    []
```

Comment: Is there a bonus reward associated with the bonus question?

Comment: My eternal gratitude sound good?

Comment: For your first question: You have to write a loop to split up `entry.getValue()` on each iteration of your `for each` loop.

Comment: How would you know which keys are not in the map if you didn't store the missing keys somewhere? Did you keep a list of missing keys?

Comment: All the possible keys are in a separate document I've loaded in through a properties file. @pczeus

Comment: Then you can loop over those keys in a separate loop and for each one do a `keywordMap.containsKey("something")` and if it is false, its not in the map then print accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
writer.print("\n"); //Line feed only
```

To:

```
writer.print("\n\r"); //Carriage return + line feed
```

Also, you have an issue that you want to break the line not on the entries of the map, but on the 3rd entry of the List stored in a single key of the map.

So, you need something like:

```
for (String key: keywordMap.keySet()) {
    List<Integer> values = keywordMap.get(key);
    writer.print(key + "=\n\r[");
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++){
         writer.print(values.get(i));
         if(i % 3 == 0){
            writer.print("\n\r");
         }
    }
    writer.print("]\n\r");
}
```

Where you are processing each key and getting it's associate List of values.
Then use a for loop to loop over the values list and on each iteration, if the value of the counter is i % 3 == 0 : or every 3rd element, print a carriage-return / line feed.